# Can't see the mistake while inserting in mongoDB via shell 3.6?

Tags: mongodb

Good evening community,

I got an problem while inserting a document in my mongoDB.

I am using the mongoshell 3.6.x

I try following:

```
db.collection.insert({
_id: 0000,
spot:"Gufi-See,
contact:{
    street: "Haldenweg 10",
    zipcode:"89423",
    city:"Gundelfingen a.d. Donau",
    homepage:"www.wasserski-gundelfingen.de",
    phone:"09073/920690"
    },
location:[
    longitude:10.328760,
    latitude:48.520839
    ]
})
```

Following error is thrown:

```
E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing } after property list @(shell):1:47
```

My problem is that i can't find the problem of the missing } ... Maybe One can help me out?! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are not closing the double quotes of the spot. Please close it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spot's name should have closed quotes like this: `spot:"Gufi-See"` and you can't store location in such way. You should change it to an object. Try:

```
db.collection.insert({
_id: 0000,
spot:"Gufi-See",
contact:{
    street: "Haldenweg 10",
    zipcode:"89423",
    city:"Gundelfingen a.d. Donau",
    homepage:"www.wasserski-gundelfingen.de",
    phone:"09073/920690"
    },
location:{
    longitude: 10.328760,
    latitude:48.520839
    }
})
```

Comment: Shame on me... sometimes can't see obvious problems... -.- Preferred for locations is an Array can you see here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/